# Clang-tidy not finding header file

Tags: c++, linux, clang-tidy

Note: This is done in RHEL 7.2 with clang 8.0.1.

I'm running the command

```
clang-tidy test.C -- -I/path/to/header.h
```

and I get the following error:

```
1 error generated.
Error while processing test.C.
test.C:28:10: error: 'header.h' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
#include "header.h"
         ^
Found compiler error(s).
```

When I build using g++, it works fine. The above include is the first include statement of the file, and there's some more after it. The file structure is complicated, so it'd be difficult to show where the files are located. I thought the -I argument would find the header, but it doesn't. So, how do I get clang-tidy to find those headers?

Answer (score 3):

Clang tools usually need a compilation database : the `compile_commands.json`.
It provides information required to build your cpp units (g.e the include directories).

You can generate this file from Make, CMake, etc. by using some external tools.

https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear is one of them.

Comment: I managed to create the `compile_commands.json file`. I would have to add my directories where all the header files are, correct?

Comment: you don't have to if the file has been generated